# Best practice for making links that take advantage of clean urls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

I'm using ASP.NET 4 and the routing engine. In my `Global.asax` I have something like this.

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
            "Items",
            "manager/items",
            "~/Manager/Item/Items.aspx"
        );
```

Is writing a link this this acceptable?:

```
<a href="/Manager/Items"></a>
```

Should I be using the `<% %>` tags and code within to retrieve the route name, "Items" in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a method like `Page.GetRouteUrl()` will most likely be the better option than outputing a `<a/>` tag directly since changes to the virtual path will be handled by `GetRouteUrl`

```
<a href="<%:Page.GetRouteUrl("Items", null)%>"></a>
```

Comment: that code outputs this url:`/manager/items?Length=5` which works, but I don't want it to say `Length=5`

Comment: do you have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Nick, I just was able to try it out, if you pass `null` as the second param it should get rid of the `?Length=5`.

Comment: It was because the overload we needed was `(string, RouteValueDictionary)`, using just `"Items"` was picking `(object)` by default which was getting us the `length=5`